# Problems installing memcached

Tags: memcached

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://www.sohailriaz.com/how-to-install-memcached-with-memcache-php-extension-on-centos-5x/) to install Memcached on a CentOS machine, and I'm not having much luck.

The instructions say to first enable rpmforge repository as follows:

`rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS//rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm`

This appears to go OK.

Then they say to install memcached by using yum:

`yum -y install memcached`

This gets the download speeds of various mirror sites, then says "Setting up Install Process", and then finally "No package memcached available".

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: These are the contents of my /etc/yum.conf file:

```
root@vps-1077739-6497 [/etc/sysconfig]# cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
exclude=apache* bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mysql* nsd* perl* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=16&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum

# Note: yum-RHN-plugin doesn't honor this.
metadata_expire=1h

installonly_limit = 5

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Comment: What version of CentOS?

Comment: Maybe snagging from RPMForge would be an option? http://pkgs.repoforge.org/memcached/ just download the rpm and install.

Comment: @jeff-ferland, My version of CentOS is 5.7.

Comment: @tim, thanks for your suggestion - I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached is in the rpmforge-extras repository and it is not enabled by default.

```
Installing:
 memcached                              i386                         1.4.7-1.el5.rfx                         rpmforge-extras                        79 k
```

You need to edit the file /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo and put "enabled = 1" instead of "enabled = 0" in the [rpmforge-extras] section and then re-run your command yum -y install memcached.

Your /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo should looks like this:

```
### Name: RPMforge RPM Repository for RHEL 5 - dag
### URL: http://rpmforge.net/
[rpmforge]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - dag
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/$basearch/rpmforge
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/mirrors-rpmforge
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge
enabled = 1
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1

[rpmforge-extras]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - extras
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/$basearch/extras
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/mirrors-rpmforge-extras
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-extras
enabled = 1
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1

[rpmforge-testing]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - testing
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/$basearch/testing
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/mirrors-rpmforge-testing
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-testing
enabled = 0
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1
```

Comment: Just for information I reproduce the case before answering on a OpenVZ VPS with your exact command

Comment: I am marking your response as the answer because it removed the issue I was having. Unfortunately, I ran into dependency issues with libevent and various Perl modules, and in the end I had to download/compile the source. These are the links I followed (in case anyone else ever has this problem): http://mrphp.com.au/code/install-memcache-cpanel-running-centos and http://alexle.net/archives/tag/libevent. The versions referred to in the links are out of date, so whoever is following the instructions should get the latest versions at the Memcached and Libevent sites.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you're doing wrong. According to http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3, RHEL5 and CentOS 6 (among others) provide memcached. CentOS5 has it in the testing branch. Perhaps if you're stuck, searching for "memcached" there for your distro will allow you a direct download that works.